# Armadillo - how to create Matrix from sparse format?

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

Let's say I have a sparse matrix.  I have it defined in the following CSV format:

`row,column,value
1,1,5
1,2,10`

In this case, the point (1,1) is equal to 5 and the point (1,2) is equal to 10.

What is an efficient way to create a matrix from this format (assuming thousands or hundreds of thousands of rows)?

In other words, I want the equivalent of running full(spconvert(m)) in Matlab, where m is the above matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use one of batch insertion constructors of `sp_mat` sparse matrix class. There is an example of how to do it in [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat):

```
// batch insertion of two values at (5, 6) and (9, 9)
umat locations;
locations << 5 << 9 << endr
          << 6 << 9 << endr;

vec values;
values << 1.5 << 3.2 << endr;

sp_mat X(locations, values);
```